# IIS Windows Server, Erro ao executar aplicação (HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden)

Tags: c#, iis-7, windows-service

estou com um problema, na hora de executar minha aplicação.
Minha aplicação é toda feita em Asp.Net MVC, usando o framework 4.6.1.
Eu publiquei ela no servidor, porém na hora de executar a aplicação, aparece o erro `HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dai eu vou la e Habilito a opção de Lista conteudo de diretório, e aparece assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu IIS
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Como está o pool, você instalou o hosting do mvc? você tem outras aplicações .net que já estão rodando nesse servidor?

Comment: Tem outra aplicação sim, ela é em asp.net, a minha tbm é asp.net só que minha aplicação é em MVC. eu tentei publicar minha aplicação no proprio computador, ou seja, eu habilitei o ISS, na maquina pelo "Adicionar ou remover recursos do windows". E lá no IIS, da maquina, ele roda normal, somente no servidor que ele da acesso negado.

Comment: E você instalou o mvc nessa máquina que não roda?

Answer (score 0):

O servidor não está conseguindo interpretar sua aplicação, garanta que todos os arquivos estão publicados corretamente, a rota default está configurada e o Application Pool está configurado como 4.0.

Comment: o Application Pool está configurado como 4.0.

Comment: eu tentei publicar minha aplicação no proprio computador, ou seja, eu habilitei o IIS, na maquina pelo "Adicionar ou remover recursos do windows". E lá no IIS, da maquina, ele roda normal, somente no servidor que ele da acesso negado

Comment: Tem alguma aplicação MVC com .NET 4.6 rodando neste servidor?